# Conditional python list with one line of code?

Tags: python, list

I have the following code, running perfectly fine. However, always trying to improve things, I was wondering if we could write this with just one line:

```
l,listSex = [], ['male1', 'female23', 'male2', 'female1', 'female2']
for s in listSex:
    if 'female' in s:
        l.append(1)
    else:
        l.append(0)
```

My problem here is how to handle the else case (as otherwise, the answer would have been pretty straightforward).

Comment: 'male' is going to be in all of them.

Answer (score 5):

Use a list comprehension with a conditional expression.

```
listsSex = ['male1', 'female23', 'male2', 'female1', 'female2']
l = [1 if 'female' in s else 0 for s in listSex]
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it work the same if I wanted to put an elif in it ?

Comment: No; conditional expressions only support either/or conditions, not a series of conditions. You can *nest* conditional expressions, but it gets ugly fast: `1 if condition1 else (2 if condition2 else 3)`. (The parentheses might be optional; I don't recall exactly how conditional expressions get parsed.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a lambda expression:

```
listSex=['male1','female23','male2','female1','female2']

l= map(lambda x: int(not('female' in x)), listSex)
```

or when using similar logic to @chepner

```
l  = map(lambda x: int(x.startswith('male')), listSex)
```